# Empty search error handling

Tags: mysql, user-interface

I am searching for items that I have created in the database when developing GUI application, I was able to retrieve data from the database, however the problem is that if I did not enter anything in the text box to search, the application returns everything from the database, what did I do incorrectly, I use this code,

```
if (txtShowTitle.Text.Equals(" "))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the title!");
}
```

Comment: which language is this in, C#/Java?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `return` there as well, otherwise it will continue further.

```
if (txtShowTitle.Text.Equals(" "))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the title!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas, I put the code in the wrong place and there should be no space between the double quotes. I got it work fine now, thank you for your suggestion.